# why parallelizing the code of this implementation's genetic algorithm for the resolution of the tsp is much slower?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am working on a university project on genetic algorithms to solve the TSP Problem and the teacher asked us to parallelize the optimize function. I tried to implement the optimize function in parallel and it works but it is much slower.
Tips?

You can find the original code here: https://github.com/Mentathiel/StackAbuseGeneticTravelingSalesman

```
public SalesmanGenome optimizeP() throws InterruptedException {
    //Setting all the constant attributes that will not change during the optimizations
    addInP.setGenerationSize(generationSize);       
    addInP.setGenomeSize(genomeSize);               
    addInP.setMutationRate(mutationRate);           
    addInP.setNumberOfCities(numberOfCities);       
    addInP.setStartingCity(startingCity);
    addInP.setTravelPrices(travelPrices);
    addInP myThreads[]= new addInP[N_THREADS];

    List<SalesmanGenome> population = initialPopulation();//RandomPopulation
    SalesmanGenome globalBestGenome = population.get(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < maxIterations; i++) {

        addInP.setPopulation(selection(population));
        addInP.setCurrentGenerationSize(0);
        addInP.setGeneration(new ArrayList<>());

        for (int j = 0; j < N_THREADS; j++) {
            myThreads[j]= new addInP();
            myThreads[j].start();
            myThreads[j].join();
        }

    population = addInP.getGeneration();//population generated each step
    addInP.setCurrentGenerationSize(0); //Resetting current Generation Size

    globalBestGenome = Collections.min(population);
    if (globalBestGenome.getFitness() < targetFitness)
        break;
    }
    return globalBestGenome;
}
```

This is the run function of my addInP class that extends thread

```
public void run()
{
    while( getCurrentGenerationSize() < generationSize){

        List<SalesmanGenome> parents = pickNRandomElements(population,2);
        List<SalesmanGenome> children = crossover(parents);
        children.set(0, mutate(children.get(0)));
        children.set(1, mutate(children.get(1)));
        generation.addAll(children);
        setCurrentGenerationSize( getCurrentGenerationSize()+2);

    }

}
```

These are the attributes of my addInP class and the methods to use the shared variable currentGenerationSize

```
private static List<SalesmanGenome> population;
private static volatile int currentGenerationSize ;
private static int generationSize;
private static int[][] travelPrices;
private static int startingCity;
private static int numberOfCities;
private static int genomeSize;
private static float mutationRate;
private static List<SalesmanGenome> generation;

public synchronized int getCurrentGenerationSize() {
    return currentGenerationSize;
}

public synchronized  static void setCurrentGenerationSize(int currentGenerationSize) {
    addInP.currentGenerationSize = currentGenerationSize;
}
```

Comment: you can divide `genome.size` in a smaller chunk and calculate score independently. this makes sense only of `genome.size` is big

Comment: As far as I can see the for loop doesn't actually need access to modify anything in it's enclosing scope. So, your tutor is probably looking for you to calculate the fittness for each genome in parallel, rather than sequentially (the for loop is sequential). So, you could fire up a thread pool of size `genome.size` and have each thread calculate the fitness of a given genome and post the result back onto the main thread where you add the result onto the fitness. This only works if the order that the fitnesses are calculated doesn't matter (which as far as I can see it doesn't).

Comment: Whether or not this is more efficient is debatable, as the thread switching adds overhead so it might end up being slower than a straight forward for loop.

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-level_parallelism